# Android Junit test giving NULLpointer exception

Tags: android

I have a question regarding Junit test case

Let say I have 2 sepearate Junit classes each having its own setup and teardown
These clases are in the same package

```
Package xyz;
void setup()
Class A
{
   func A.f()
}
void teardown()

Package xyz;
void setup()
Class B
{
  func B.f()
{
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.tostring());
}
} 
void teardown()
```

My question is when i print this in the console, the new instantiated class a it shows null.
Why is this so???